# Creating Upload Document button - upload hangs and never closes

Tags: lookup-column, button, document-upload

Trying to create an upload document button for a SharePoint 2013 library.  I have some metadata that is necessary for user to enter upon upload.  When I grab the URL for the UploadEx.aspx and link to button it doesn't function correctly.  Seems to hang and states This shouldn't take long and constant spinning circle.  Document does upload but upload box stays open and never show the columns necessary for user to populate.

URL:  .../_layouts/15/UploadEx.aspx?List=%7b1F11BD30-369D-4775-B47D-2C6FCB256754%7d&RootFolder=%2fsites%2fAllianceImaging%2fOQS%2fAnnual+Physicist+Evaluations&Source=https%3a%2f%2fcorp.ahcsusa.com%2fsites%2fAllianceImaging%2fOQS%2fAnnual+Physicist+Evaluations%2fForms%2fAllItems.aspx&IsDlg=1

Answer (score 0):

from my view the link should only be:

```
.../_layouts/15/UploadEx.aspx?List=%7b1F11BD30-369D-4775-B47D-2C6FCB256754%7d&RootFolder=&IsDlg=1
```

This is what I have and it works.